# How do we define a jsonb and UUID field in sqlx rust?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I have a Postgres table having three fields
`id` which is a `bigserial`, `meta` a `jsonb` field and a uuid `UUID` field.

```rust
pub struct MetaLogs {

    pub id:i64,
    pub uuid: <what type should I give here > 
    pub meta: < What type should I give here > 
}
```

I am using `sqlx` ORM for `Rust`.
Although I understood that I have to add

```
features = [ "runtime-tokio", "macros" ,"postgres","json","uuid"]
```

I was unable to figure it out how to proceed after that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sqlx` provides both `Json` and `Uuid` type implementations for PostgreSQL. See [uuid.rs](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/7c4c1856988ecc2ac2b8892453aeee09c245257f/sqlx-core/src/postgres/types/uuid.rs) and [json.rs](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/f0f93c4f79d18ff85af6364837fc8157ec444125/sqlx-core/src/postgres/types/json.rs).

Note the Json type will resolve to jsonb internally which is as you'd expect.

Sample:

```
use sqlx::{types::Uuid, types::Json};
pub struct MetaLogs {
    pub id: i64,
    pub uuid: Uuid, 
    pub meta: Json,
}
```

Comment: This requires to add "uuid" to features.